# Is this a problematic amount of passive water usage?

Tags: plumbing, well

Sorry I don't have any data about depth of well or any other history of it. Trying to help out an elderly friend and they are not very clear on some details.

Water meter shows about 0.10 gallons per minute of usage even when everything (as far as I know) is turned off. Is this amount of usage likely to be problematic on a private well? Recently the well ran out of water* and I'm trying to decide whether it's worth chasing down this leakage or if the problem is likely to be elsewhere.

*details on how I know it ran out of water: pressure would be ok for a bit and then drop to zero. After leaving the master valve off for a while we turned it back on and listened at the well casing. We could hear a very dull hum for a while and then a much louder one that sounded like the water level had dropped to the level of the pump.

Other possible reasons it might have run out:

1 - local water table conditions may have changed due to recent development across the road and lower-than-normal rainfall last couple months

2 - tenant could have done something crazy like take an hours-long shower. No reason to suspect anything but not completely trusting them either

In case you're wondering why there's a meter on a well: it's because that's how they pay for their sewer bill: private well but public sewer.

Comment: 6 gallons per hour is a fair bit of water. Whether it's problematic or not depends on where it's going.

Comment: I'd suggest looking for non-obvious leaks (i.e. ones that really are adding to the sewer load) such as water softeners (I've had some experience with those going haywire) and toilets that don't quite shut off. For a low output well, the 144 gallons of "leak" daily may be significant - certainly for many occupants that may exceed the normal use, and if you are paying sewerage rates on it can be expensive, too. Hmm - is there a reverse osmosis water filter here?

Comment: I have worked on many well systems,  0.1 gallons should not be a problem most homes to get a loan need 5.0 gallons a minute well test for 3 hours. I have found some cases where an outside faucet was left on caused the well to run dry. If many of the faucets or toilets drip this could quickly add up to 0.1 gallons on a large system but unless the well is going dry it should not be a problem. A well flow test with the static water level checked prior to and 30 minutes after a 3-4 hour flow test would provide more info on the health of the well.

Comment: @Ecnerwal there is no RO system or water softener